# javascript regular expression allow a-z A-Z 0-9 & @ etc

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I modify my existing regular expression:

```
/^[a-z A-Z0-9._,-]+$/
```

So that it will allow the following:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 & @ . $ % - , ( ) : ; ` - space
```

Thanks

Comment: You can simply add those extra elements like: /^[a-z A-Z0-9._,-\(\(\$\@]+$/

Comment: @AlecSmart you don't even need to quote the `$` or `@`

Comment: And anyway -- given the list of _allowed_ characters, wouldn't it be shorter to build a list of disallowed ones?

Comment: @fge `Not invalid` does not imply `valid`. If you want to match bananas, and the fruit is not an apple, it's also possible that the fruit is an orange.

Comment: @RobW I was just telling to build a character class of non allowed characters: matching _just one_ renders the input invalid

Comment: @fge, don't know if you were serious, but although the list of invalid characters on a standard (English/US) keyboard is fairly short, something like: `!#^*{}[]/<>\|=+'"~`, you've also got to allow for all sorts of other characters, like `¿¡` etc. @RobW - I think not invalid does imply valid if your list of invalids is exhaustive - it's just that making it exhaustive is way more work than just listing the valid things...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following pattern will do. Inside square braces, only `-` (and `]`, if included) has to be escaped using a backslash (`\`).

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9&@.$%\-,():;` ]+$/
#^ ^                       ^^
#^ ^                       ^End of string
#^ ^                       At least one occurrence
#^ Characters to match
#Begin of string
```

Comment: I have to add, `^` should also be escaped *if* it's the first character within the square braces. At that position, it has the special meaning of "negated expression". For instance, `[^0-9]` matches any non-number character.